# Linq - select where ancestors contain this?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

sometimes, i just feel dumb...

i have a simple class:

```
public class myClass
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ParentChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a list that contains the class:

```
List<myClass> myItems = new List<myClass>
```

further down the code, i feed the list with classes.

now, i want to delete an item from the list.
but, since an item can have children and grandchilds etc...
i want to delete everything related..

was thinking of something like:
(pseudo code )

```
var List<myClass> itemsToDelete = myItems.Where(i => i.Ancestors.Contains(myItemId));
```

but i dont really have the brains atm to know how to write it exactly... :\
i do have the `.Ancestors` function...
just need help with the lambda linq

```
public List<Channel> Ancestors
{
    get
    {
        List<MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel> result = new List<MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel>();

        Channel channel = this;

        while (channel != null)
        {
            result.Add(channel);
            channel = myChannels.Where(c => c.ParentChannelId == this.Id).First();
        }
        result.Reverse();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** guess i did not explain myself as i should...
i have all the properties like ancestors, children parent etc...
i want to select all the classes that might contain the specific class...

Comment: you want to delete the content of var List<myClass> itemsToDelete  ?

Comment: What's the code for the `Ancestors` property?

Comment: @dknaack - no, i want to fill it with the channels to delete.

Comment: @BoltClock - added to Q.

Comment: The Ancestors property does not exist. Please provide more source code.

Comment: Now I am a big fan of LINQ and all that, but I don't think it should be considered the only way of solving enumerable problems. A much more optimal solution would be using yield instead of constructing some hashset or list, reversing it and returning, see @Merlyn Morgan-Graham ´s answer

Comment: So wait... If this is what you want to do, what was wrong with your itemsToDelete pseudocode?

Comment: ...why do you say that there's no Ancestors when the code is (now) right there on the original post? (hence downvote)

Comment: @sq33G: Him saying it was pseudo-code lead me to believe he didn't have such a property.  In my rush to answer, I missed where he said "I do have the .Ancestors function".  See my edited answer.

Comment: @sq33G - the problem with my pseucode is .Contains need to be fed an item, while i want to feed it an id of an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-read your question, especially the last part where you said you already have `.Ancestors`, and now it makes more sense.

Do this to get your list of items to delete:

```
List<MyClass> itemsToDelete = myItems
    .Where(i => i.Id == myItemId)
    .SelectMany(i => i.Ancestors)
    .Concat(myItems) // Want to delete these too, not just the ancestors
    .ToList()
    ;
```

Then you can `foreach` through the result, and remove them from the original list.

I'd suggest keeping these in a `Dictionary<int, MyClass>` or a `HashSet<MyClass>` instead of a list, since removal will be *way* faster.

For a `HashSet`, you'll have to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or create an `IEqualityComparer<MyClass>` implementation to provide those methods.

**Before Edit:**

I wouldn't write my code this way.  I'd simply create a `Dictionary<int, MyClass>` instead of a list.  It will do a lookup way faster than anything involving ancestors/tree traversal.

But here is how to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish:

If you're using Linq to Objects (as opposed to Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities), make a property called `Parent` on `MyClass`, of the correct type, instead of trying to link them by `Id`.

Then you can make an `Ancestors` property fairly easily:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> Ancestors
{
    get
    {
        MyClass current = this;

        while(current != null)
        {
            current = current.Parent;
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't edit the class, make an extension method called `GetAncestors`.

Then you can use something very similar to the code you wrote in your question:

```
List<MyClass> itemsToDelete = myItems
    .Where(i => i.Ancestors.Any(a => a.Id == myItemId))
    .ToList();
```

**Linq to Entities**

If you are using Linq to Entities, create a navigation property of the type `MyClass` to navigate to the parent, and do the same thing.  Note that this might cause re-queries.  Not sure the Linq can or would get translated into a hierarchical query.

Comment: i have ancestors and parent and children. i just need to know how to select all the classes that contains the specific class.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it using a hashset and RemoveAll method.

```
var itemsToDelete = new HashSet<myClass>(otherItems);
myItems.RemoveAll(i => itemsToDelete.Contains(i));
```

**RemoveAll Method**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx